# Error PLS-00103 when create package with Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying create package with oracle, although I have read many examples in docs oracle and built code same this tutorial but I still error this. 
The following code:

```
create table manage_emplyee
(
    f_name varchar(20),
    l_name varchar(20)
);

// Specification

create or replace package fn2
    as
        procedure manage_emplyee(v_fname in VARCHAR2, v_lname in VARCHAR2);
        procedure manage_emplyee_delete(v_fname in VARCHAR2);
    end;
/

create or replace package body fn2 
as
    --Procedure Implementation 
procedure manage_emplyee(v_fname in VARCHAR2, v_lname in VARCHAR2)
is
begin
    insert into manage_emplyee VALUES (v_lname, v_lname);
end manage_emplyee;


// body

procedure manage_emplyee_delete (v_fname in VARCHAR2)
is
begin
    delete manage_emplyee where v_fname =  v_fname;
end manage_emplyee_delete;

end fn2;
/
```

Error

> > PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:
> >     begin end function pragma procedure

Please help me fix it, thanks so much !

Comment: Is this a typo - `procedure MANAGE_SPHERO_delete` your procedure name is difference in specification and body.

Comment: I edited, but It also error.

Comment: Firstly, why are you using c++ style comments in plsql? get rid of them. Your procedure manage_emplyee_delete is deleting the table manage_emplyee_delete , which is not the correct table name, please correct it.

Answer (score 0):

There are many things incorrect, so here is a correct version.

Run the table script first -

```
create table manage_emplyee
(
    f_name varchar(20),
    l_name varchar(20)
);
```

Run the Spec script after that

```
create or replace package fn2
as
    procedure manage_emplyee(v_fname  VARCHAR2,
                             v_lname  VARCHAR2);
    procedure manage_emplyee_delete(v_fname  VARCHAR2);
end;
/
```

Run the body script after that

```
create or replace package  body fn2 
as

    procedure manage_emplyee(v_fname  VARCHAR2, v_lname  VARCHAR2)
    is
    begin
        insert into manage_emplyee VALUES (v_lname, v_lname);
    end ;

    procedure manage_emplyee_delete (v_fname  VARCHAR2)
    is
    begin
        delete from manage_emplyee where f_name =  v_fname;
    end ;
 end;
/
```

1. The syntax for delete from table_name was incorrect.
2. I am sure, you want to match f_name from table with v_fname from the input variable to delete the data. Earlier you were matching v_fname with v_fname in your code, which will always be true (except for when its passed NULL) and you would end up loosing all your test data

*NOTE - 
Adding `IN` explicitly is not required, the default type is `IN` for parameters in  PLSQL procedures

Comment: I tried test your code, but it still error expecting begin end function pragma procedure. help me fix it

Comment: @TháiSơn - when compiling, did you try to compile all the code at once or did you just compile one part at once, which tool are you using to compile ? I tried compiling it at dbfiddle - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=30e1234dd11fe8d334352da9f65e628a and its working for me

Comment: I use navicat to compile and I compiled one part at once. It's error when compiling at create package body

Comment: @TháiSơn - Can you try to compile using plain old SQL Plus. I am sure, you have it installed. no ? :) I am not sure, why navicat would be throwing that error, before any single part, make sure, there is no other text in the editor

Comment: Can I have yet to install SQL Plus, Thanks you so much